# Apache Wicket how to render a (non-wicket) response page

Tags: apache, http, post, wicket, apache-httpclient-4.x

I'm using Apache Wicket and I have following problem:

Inside a onSubmit() method I am sending a POST request to external web address with **Apache httpClient**. As a response I get html (inside my response object).

How can I get Wicket to render this html in browser?

So basically what I'm trying to do here, is simply what would normally happen if I submitted a html form to this web address. However for security reasons I don't want to give user pages containing forms that contain this data I'm trying to send.

Comment: Is it just an HTML snippet you want to render or a complete HTML page with external CSS references etc.? If it is just a snippet you could simply use a Label and call `setEscapeModelStrings(false)` before rendering.

Comment: It's a complete HTML page I want to render. Thanks anyway.

Comment: You could subclass WebPage and override getMarkupStream to return a stream containing the desired HTML.

Comment: Displaying a page sent to you by another web site isn't exactly safe either. In fact it is potentially far more dangerous than showing users the form fields they submit.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the response via getResponse() in any component. (I assume the onSubmit() is on a form).

How about something like:

```
getResponse().reset();
getResponse().write(htmlPage);
```

`htmlPage` should be a `CharSequence` containing the html page to be rendered.